# Laravel переадресовать пользователя с POST запросом

Tags: php, laravel, http

Предположим, есть контроллер SimpleController

В нем есть метод,

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
   //Я делаю что-то на сервере и мне нужно отправить пользвательский post запрос на другой урл с параметрами
   //return redirect()->withPost()...
}
```

Как это сделать?

Comment: Отправляете POST "на другой URL" данного домена ?

Comment: POST на URL другого домена

Comment: Вы пытаетесь отправить POST запрос без редиректа ,то есть остаться на той жe странице,или перейти на нее `на другой URL с параметрами` ? поясните `return redirect()->withPost()` строку из вопроса

Comment: Добавьте подробной информации к вопросу чтоб могли дать более точный ответ.

Comment: Уточните, какие данные требуется отправить, те же, что пришли в метод `foo` или какие-то другие сформированные уже в методе `foo`?

Answer (score 1):

> //return redirect()->withPost()...

Если вас интересует редирект с пост параметрами то :

пошлите пост данные во `view.path` которые получили в `action foo()`.
В `view.path`создайте форму с `input` со значениями из переданных `post` параметров, и с `post` методом, а потом спомощью `javascript` отправьте `post` данные дальше,куда вы хотели.

Пример `action` :

```
public function foo(Request $request)
{
   //Я делаю что-то на сервере и передаю пост параметры во view
   return view('view.path', ['post_data' => $request->all();
}
```

Пример `view.path` :

```
<form id="myForm" action="my/redirect/path" method="post">
<?php
    foreach ($post_data as $a => $b) {
        echo '<input type="hidden" name="'.htmlentities($a).'" value="'.htmlentities($b).'">';
    }
?>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
</script>
```

Comment: И вы думаете что этот ваш метод оптималный?  переадресовать на другую страницу и после через JS нажать на отправку? )

Comment: @Arsen Да конечно.Это очень даже оптимальный вариант.Что вам не нравится ? ведь это решает задачу автора вопроса.В чем проблема ? сли разъясните то я буду вам благодарен. http://stackoverflow.com/a/5576700/6120970

Comment: Это не может быть оптимальным, т.к вашим методом вы выполняете задание в несколько шагов'. Оптимально это возможность сделать всё  одним "шагом" - CURL

Comment: @Arsen `//return redirect()->withPost()...`  Я учитывал эту строку автора.перенаправление с `post` параметрами а не обращение постом.Если вы знакомы с фреймворком Laravel то `redirect()` перенаправляет на указанную страницу. Тут можно почитать https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirects